# Running Batch Script on remote Server via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, remote-server

I need to connect to some remote servers from a client (same domain as the servers) once connected, I need to run a batch file:

I've done so with this code:

```
$Username = 'USER'
$Password = 'PASSWORD'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass

try {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName "SERVER1" -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock -ErrorAction Stop {
        Start-Process "C:\Users\nithi.sundar\Desktop\Test.bat"
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host "error"
}
```

This script does not give any errors, but it doesn't seem to be executing the batch script.

any input on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try replacing

```
invoke-command -computername "SERVER1" -credential $Cred -ScriptBlock -ErrorAction stop { Start-Process "C:\Users\nithi.sundar\Desktop\Test.bat" }
```

with

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "Server1" -credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'C:\Users\nithi.sund
ar\Desktop\Test.bat'"}
```

Comment: I am trying to make the path dynamically, but it's giving error -> 
*$toinstall = ('"' + "cmd.exe /c " + $inputdata.TargetFolder + '\' + $inputdata.InstallerBat + '"')*
   -------------------------------
 *Invoke-Command -ComputerName $inputdata.TargetMachineName -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:$toinstall}*
 -------------------------------
**Error : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is null.**

Comment: [Invoke-Expression considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible that the code you posted ran without errors, because you messed up the order of the argument to `Invoke-Command`. This:

```
Invoke-Command ... -ScriptBlock -ErrorAction Stop { ... }
```

should actually look like this:

```
Invoke-Command ... -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock { ... }
```

Also, **DO NOT** use `Invoke-Expression` for this. It's [practically always the wrong tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/) for whatever you need to accomplish. You also don't need `Start-Process` since PowerShell can run batch scripts directly:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "SERVER1" -ScriptBlock {
    C:\Users\nithi.sundar\Desktop\Test.bat
} -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction Stop
```

If the command is a string rather than a bare word you need to use the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators), though:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "SERVER1" -ScriptBlock {
    & "C:\Users\nithi.sundar\Desktop\Test.bat"
} -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction Stop
```

You could also invoke the batch file with `cmd.exe`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "SERVER1" -ScriptBlock {
    cmd /c "C:\Users\nithi.sundar\Desktop\Test.bat"
} -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction Stop
```

If for some reason you must use `Start-Process` you should add the parameters `-NoNewWindow` and `-Wait`.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "SERVER1" -ScriptBlock {
    Start-Process 'C:\Users\nithi.sundar\Desktop\Test.bat' -NoNewWindow -Wait
} -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction Stop
```

By default `Start-Process` runs the invoked process asynchronously (i.e. the call returns immediately) and in a separate window. That is most likely the reason why your code didn't work as intended.