# Executing a Batch file on remote server from powershell command

Tags: powershell, batch-file, teamcity, remote-server

I'm currently trying to implement the functionality mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125893/running-batch-script-on-remote-server-via-powershell) question, but I haven't had any success. I'm trying to run this on a TeamCity server to copy some files and then run a batch file. The robocopy works perfectly but the execution for the `Invoke-Command` seems to fail but it doesn't throw any error in any of the ways I've tried.

This is my code:

```
$deploymentComputerName = 'server.name.com'
$robocopyPath = 'C:\Windows\System32\robocopy.exe'

try {
  $deploymentShare = "\\" + $deploymentComputerName + "\folder"
  $deploymentPackageDirectory = 'c:\local\route'
  $invokeRoute = "C:\Route\batchFile.bat"

  &$robocopyPath /E /PURGE $deploymentPackageDirectory $deploymentShare /r:0 /XF "LibSassHost.dll" "LibSassHost.Native-64.dll" "libsass.dll"

  Write-Host "Attempting to run it with the FIRST method"
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $deploymentComputerName -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c '$invokeRoute'"}
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $deploymentComputerName -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c $invokeRoute"}

  Write-Host "Attempting to run it with the SECOND method - " $invokeRoute
  Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { "$deploymentShare\batchFile.bat" } -ComputerName $deploymentComputerName

  Write-Host "Finished trying to run the methods"    
} catch {
  Write-Host "Error running powershell file"
}
```

Comment: `"$deploymentShare\batchFile.bat"` -> `& "$using:deploymentShare\batchFile.bat"`

Comment: So that will end up like this when executing?
`Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { & "$using:\\server.name.com\folder\batchFile.bat" } -ComputerName $deploymentComputerName`

Comment: No. Like this: `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { & "\\bar.example.com\share\batchFile.bat" } -ComputerName 'foo.example.com'`.